# Get the access token in localStorage generated by MSAL.JS and put it in Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, msal.js

Good day,

I'm trying to implement MSAL.js in my application. Basically, I'm able to implement the msal.js and log in using my email from the AD. I also configured the msal to save my `tokenid` and `accessToken` in my `localStorage`

The `accessToken` is working in my backend because I tested it using Postman software. But in my app, I don't know how can acquire and put it in my `Axios` header because the `key` in the `localStorage` shows like this:

[image]

Where it has a `Key` in the localStorage of an object.

```
{"authority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/","clientId":"CLIENT_ID","scopes":"CLIENT_ID","homeAccountIdentifier":"SOME_HASH"}
```

With an value of:

```
accessToken: 'TOKEN_HASH_HERE'
idToken: 'TOKEN_HASH_HERE'
expiresIn: 'TOKEN_HASH_HERE'
homeAccountIdentifier: 'TOKEN_HASH_HERE'
```

I need to get the access token to be able to put it in my `axios` header like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessTokenFromMsal}`
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about MSAL.js but can't you just write those values with simple string keys in the local storage?
`localStorage.setItem('authority', '...'); localStorage.setItem('accessToken', '...')`
This way you'll have no issue getting them back with `getItem`

Comment: those are auto generated by the package of `msal.net` not good to modify or else, it will broken or detect by the authority to be as false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `msal` package in your project, you can visit this [samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/) from Github Repo of MSAL Azure AD.

Take a look at this AuthProvider.js on [line 70](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/)

[image]
Basically, you can put a `console.log(tokenResponse)` after the `if(tokenResponse)` statement. Like this:

```
if(tokenResponse){
    console.log(tokenResponse)
}
```

On your console log, you'll see the details of the token response. It's tricky but the parameter name of the `accessToken` that you're looking is `idToken.rawIdToken` not the `accessToken` (because as far as I know, the access token is for the request token to the ms graph).

Then here's you can set an item to your localStorage.

```
if (tokenResponse) {
localStorage.setItem("webApiAccessToken", tokenResponse.idToken.rawIdToken)
...
}
```

So you'll be able to put it on your request header. Like if you case, using `axios`

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('webApiAccessToken')}`
```

Note: Make sure to clear that `webApiAccessToken` in the `localStorage` whenever the user has clicked the logout method. To do that, just simply `localStorage.removeItem("webApiAccessToken")`

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Dislike this approach. One more thing to maintain a duplicate of. What if the user clears the msal data manually? No logout, no clear-localstorage. After the login, just another thing to keep in mind an check/set/delete/update. The token is already stored by msal. A direct access would be way more efficient and less error prone.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of how to get an access token from local storage using `@azure/msal-browser` npm package. The key to all of this is that publicClientApplication.getAllAccounts() gives what appears to be direct access to the id token in local storage to allow you to craft the long localStorage item key.

```
    let account = publicClientApplication.getAllAccounts()[0];
    console.log(`${account.homeAccountId}-login.microsoftonline.com-accesstoken-${AuthConfig.getClientId()}-${AuthConfig.getTenantId()}-${ACCESS_TOKEN_FULLY_QUALIFIED_SCOPE}---`);
```

All the variables you should have in your application. publicClientApplication comes from a singleton that you should have then client id, tenant id and scope are all core items to OAuth that you should already be aware of.

This appears to be the only way to get direct access to localStorage. I've looked deeper into the msal libraries and the access method is protected so although this could break in a patch or minor package update this code is actually really important, because msal underutilizes and outright misutilizes the cache for things like giving you stale id tokens when calling acquireTokenSilent and excessively calling openid-configuration even when a fully valid token already exists in the cache.